# edit pythonpath in this file

Tags: python, xcode, usdz

Hello and good evening!

I am having quite a problem with trying to get `usdzconvert` to run.

The error I'm getting is

```
/Users/diamoniquedanner/Downloads/usdpython/USD.command ; exit;
diamoniquedanner@Diamoniques-MacBook-Air ~ % /Users/diamoniquedanner/Downloads/usdpython/USD.command ; exit;
For FBX support, edit PYTHONPATH in this file (USD.command) or your shell configuration file
```

I have done the following:

1. Downloaded the USDPython package provided by Apple
2. Set my Command Line tools to Xcode 11

I think it's pertaining to the `USD.command` file. I don't know how to edit it properly.

Here is the code in the USD.command file:

```
#!/bin/sh
BASEPATH=$(dirname "$0")

export PATH=$PATH:$BASEPATH/USD:$PATH:$BASEPATH/usdzconvert;
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$BASEPATH/USD/lib/python

# uncomment to set the PYTHONPATH to FBX Bindings here:
# export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ Python\ SDK/2019.0/lib/Python27_x86

if [[ $PYTHONPATH == *"FBX"* ]]; then
    :
else 
    echo "For FBX support, edit PYTHONPATH in this file (USD.command) or your shell configuration file"
fi

$SHELL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tels you, as well as the comment in the command file, in order to use FBX, you need to point python to where the fbx bindings are located.

If you've installed them into the default location, you can simply uncomment the line that starts with:

```sh
#export ....
```

To uncomment a line in a shell script remove the # from the beginning of the line